# Trouble running three events in SELECT MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run three events in a SELECT. Individually they seem to run fine but when I lump them together they do not work together resulting in error messages.

Trying to:

1. Convert TZ to local TZ
2. Change DATE FORMAT to Month Day Time
3. Select only records with an bor_id >166

Any help with the formatting for this would be GREAT. I can't seem to get it right.

```
select CONVERT_TZ(`borsignupdate`,'-08:00',@@global.time_zone) DATE_FORMAT(MAX(borsignupdate),'%M %e %l:%i%p') AS maxdate 
FROM borsurvey 
WHERE bor_id>166
```

Comment: missing , before DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Generally speaking, one shouldn't need to use `CONVERT_TZ()`, as merely setting the session [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) causes MySQL to automatically convert `TIMESTAMP` results (which ought to suffice in most applications).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `CONVERT_TZ` call in the argument to `DATE_FORMAT`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(MAX(borsignupdate), '-08:00', @@global.time_zone), '%M %e %l:%i%p') AS maxdate
FROM borsurvey
WHERE bor_id > 166
```

In your question in the comment, you're missing parentheses around the arguments to `DATE_FORMAT`, and you have some of the arguments to `CONVERT_TZ` outside its parentheses. This is basic syntax of 90% of programming languages, I'm not sure why you're having so much trouble with it.

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(borsignupdate, '-08:00', @@global.time_zone), '%M %e %l:%i%p') AS localtime
FROM borsurvey
WHERE bor_id > 166
```

It's basically the same as the previous query, except without the `MAX()` call around `borsignupdate`.

Comment: Thanks much Barman, That worked GREAT! One more quesion, in the next table wiht all the data I am trying to change the date/time output to localtime too. I tool MAX out becasue the table shows all records sin 166. But I can;t get it to run. Having teouble with the syntax and not able to decphier the problem using  php.<br> So trying to get this to run: $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT CONVERT_TZ(borsignupdate) '-08:00', @@global.time_zone, '%M %e %l:%i%p', AS localtime FROM borsurvey WHERE bor_id > 166 ORDER BY bornamelast ASC;") 
                or die(mysql_error());

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments since they have no formatting, but it looks like you're missing the parentheses around the argument to `DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, Got it working! I'm new to php and mysql and it's the 'crossing the 'T's' and dotting the 'I' that gets me turned around sometimes.<br> The last thing I need to do on this project is to display in a table a column that substitutes text for a number. Say the value called is '1' but I want to display the word 'apple' instead. Sort of a product inventory numder vs product description.<br>Is there a way to do this with the SELECT command? Ask for a value (1) but display it AS (apple)? or is maybe better to use a Union or Join SELECT. Appreciate your comments. Rick

Comment: Use a table that has product IDs and names, and join with it.

Comment: HTML doesn't work in comments, don't write <br>. If you have a different issue, ask a new question.